# Returning JSON response from Spring Exception Handler

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using below mentioned Spring code to handle exception and return response to client. Since I have used ResponseBody annotation here , I was expecting spring to return JSON response in case of error but I see below response received at client end (JSON response is inside responseText instead of directly return to client). Please advice how I can return JSON response to Caller-

**Response received at Client End :-**

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"status":false,"msg":"User Data not available","r…"MARSAPI003","noOfRecords":0,"responseList":null}", responseJSON: Object, status: 403, statusText: "Forbidden"}
```

**Spring Code :-**

```
@ExceptionHandler(MarsUnAuthorizedOperation.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
public MarsResponse unAuthorizedOperationExceptionHandler(final Exception ex){
    final MarsResponse response = new MarsResponse();
    response.setNoOfRecords(0);
    response.setMsg(ex.getMessage());
    response.setResponseCode(marsMessageProperties.getUnauthorizedOperationErrorCd());
    response.setResponseMessage(marsMessageProperties.getUnauthorizedOperationErrorMsg());
    response.setStatus(false);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I think it may be interfering with @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) annotation (which causes some other handler to further process it). Try removing it and also make sure, that the class itself is annotated with @ControllerAdvice. I guess you don't need this advice after over a year has passed, but I'm leaving it here for people who stray here too.

Comment: Try to add @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) at the top of the class.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's your @ResponseBody annotation that is preventing spring from marshalling your MarsResponse Object to a JSON Object.  Try removing that and checking again.