# Returning response entity from an Exception handler [Spring]

Tags: java, spring

I use the following code to handle all exceptions of type `RuntimeException` in class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`

```
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> RuntimeExceptionHandler(RuntimeException e) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
    response.put("message", e.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

It retuns the following response to the client in case of a `ValidationException`:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1496377230943,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "javax.validation.ValidationException",
  "message": "Name does not meet expectations",
  "path": "/signup"
}
```

It is not what I expected. The status code is not `BAD_REQUEST` and the json is different from `response`.

It works fine if I change `JSONObject` to `String` and pass in a string message instead of a json object. I also put a break point before `return` statement and the `response` looks fine.

**Note**: There is another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382417/returning-json-response-from-spring-exception-handler) which:

1. Has no accepted answer.
2. Is annotating the method with `@ResponseBody` which I didn't.
3. Is not using `JSONObject`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, the response is not what it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix if you require a returned JSON format:

```
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
 public ResponseEntity<String> RuntimeExceptionHandler(RuntimeException e) {
  JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
  response.put("message", e.getMessage());
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(response.toString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
 }
```